# how to convert char* pointer address to int in c++

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

how can i convert a char* address to int?
in cygwin, i've got the error as follow:

test.cpp:31:80: 错误：从‘char*’到‘int’的转换损失精度 [-fpermissive]
   cout << "hex:0x" << setw(8) << left << hex << reinterpret_cast(&pchar[i])

(translate: Error, the conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ will lose precision)

following is my source code:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 0x12345678;
    char *pchar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num);
    if (0x12 == *pchar)
    {
        cout << "big-end" << endl;
    }
    else if (0x78 == *pchar)
    {
        cout << "little-end" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "wtf" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        cout << "hex:0x" << setw(8) << left << hex << reinterpret_cast<int>(pchar + i)
            << "val:0x" << hex << static_cast<int>(pchar[i]) << endl;
    }



    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you output it "as is"?

Comment: We can't understand your error message

Comment: ... and little endian is not 0x78 from your code.

Comment: @Ternvein ? Please explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't: the behaviour would be *undefined*. This is because a `char*` is unrelated to an `int`.

In your case why not use `%p` as the format specifier for the pointer? (Strictly speaking you should convert the argument to a `void*` or `const void*`).

`cout` does this automatically for you:

`cout << (void*)(pchar);`

Comment: ...but you can just print the pointer because there is already an overload for `operator<<` where the right hand side is a `const void *`. Isn't that what he wants to do?

Comment: then, if I want to see a float's binary data in memory.  how can i do this, it's better to show this data 1byte by 1byte using hex.

Comment: u should ask that as another question.